# Вставка Html в Span

Tags: javascript, html, span

Есть такой код:

```html
<span title="Just span elem">
  <i class="logo-icon">
    //some logo
  </i>
  "10.00"
</span>
```

Мне нужно с помощью JS изменять значение в `span`. Делаю это так: `var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML = "11.12";` Все работает, но лого тоже пропадает когда меняю значение. Как можно его поменять, что бы при этом лого осталось на месте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное проще всего:

```
var currentHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
var currentHTML = currentHTML.slice(0,-5);
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML = currentHTML+"11.12";
```

Comment: Тогда нужно так же удалить 5 предыдущих символов в конце которые есть в примере: `10.00`.

Comment: Добавил удаление

Comment: В общем для автора вопроса: если у вас там строго 5 символов будет то этот ответ действительно может подойти, но в ином случае вам стоит поместить число в дополнительный блок что бы удобно обращаться к нему.

Comment: И если кавычки действительно не считаются еще двумя символами)

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `+=` должен помочь так как он добавит данные в элемент, а не заменит их. Ответ на эту тему уже дан, но я могу предложить лишь сократить его код:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML += "11.12";
```

Если внутри элемента уже есть данные то ваш код неоптимальный. Я бы посоветовал добавить еще один блок `<span>` внутри данного и работать с ним напрямую вашим же кодом, так будет проще чем изобретать велосипед заново делая поиск картинки в элементе и отделяя ее от прочего содержимого тега что бы исправить лишь 5 символов.

HTML:

```
<span title="Just span elem">
  <i class="logo-icon">
    //some logo
  </i>
  <span id="number">10.00</span>
</span>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsById('number').innerHTML = "11.12";
```

Comment: а что если добавление ещё одного блока не возможно?То есть нужно именно работать с тем HTML, который указан в вопросе

Comment: Тогда см. мой ответ

Comment: @Максим Буяков да, тогда используйте другой ответ, но я решил что вам стоит знать что это неправильно, делайте с этой информацией что вам угодно.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
   определяем DOM узел в переменную node
   node.childNodes -- коллекция дочерних элементов узла
   node.childNodes[node.childNodes.length-1] -- последний узел 
   textContent --- строка
*/
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
    node.childNodes[node.childNodes.length-1].textContent = "11.12"
```